# How do I show the post title if an advanced custom field hasn't been used?

Tags: posts, wp-query, loop, advanced-custom-fields, title

I've got an archive page for to display custom post types.

Within the WP_Query that displays the custom posts types I want to display an ACF (Advanced Custom Field) or, if the user hasn't filled out the ACF, then the title should appear.

I've tried this and the ACF field displays ok, but when it's not filled out, the title doesn't display, just the content of the post instead.

Here's the code I have (just for the title section):

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'project', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => 'menu_order' ) ); ?>

<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="project col-md-4">
    <div class="col-xs-12 short-testimonial">

        <?php if(get_field('short_testimonial')): ?>

        <?php the_field('short_testimonial'); ?>

        <?php else: ?>

        <?php echo the_title(); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

    </div>
```

Comment: `the_title()`, just like `the_field()`, already echoes, so you don’t need the `echo` in front of it. Not sure if that’s the issue, but it’s something I noticed.

Comment: Other than that though, the code looks fine. The only issue would be is if  `get_field('short_testimonial')` isn't actually empty or false when it's not filled out. What do you see if you dump it with `var_dump(get_field('short_testimonial'))`?

Answer (score 0):

If in doubt, check the documentation first: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/

**Check if value exists**

This example shows how to check if a value exists for a field.

```
$value = get_field( 'text_field' );

if ( $value ) {
    echo $value;
} else {
    echo 'empty';
}
```

So, in for your case you would need to use:

```
<?php

$short_testimonial = get_field( 'short_testimonial' );

if ( $short_testimonial ) {
    echo $short_testimonial;
} else {
    the_title();
}

?>
```

Also, you should note, as others have mentioned, that you don't need to echo `the_title()` as it echoes itself...

Comment: While it's probably better practice to code this way, the result of this code would be the same as the original code, given the same return value from `get_field('short_testimonial')`.

Comment: @Mat thanks for the example, but I've tried it and I'm still getting the content instead of the title. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score -3):

You should try removing "echo" from "the_title()".

This should work

```
<div class="project col-md-4">
     <div class="col-xs-12 short-testimonial">
          <?php 
               if( get_field( 'short_testimonial' ) ): 
               the_field( 'short_testimonial' );
               else:
               the_title();
               endif;
          ?>    
     </div>
</div>
```

You could also look at the official documentation [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title).

You will notice that *the_title* already **displays it by default**.

```
<?php the_title( $before, $after, $echo ); ?>
```

Comment: Check the documentation - https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/

Comment: While `echo` doesn't need to be there, it wouldn't cause this problem.

Comment: @Mat, you don't need to add "get_field" to a variable before checking it on a statment

Comment: @JacobPeattie you're right... but I've had experiences in the past where removing echo solved the problem. So it is worth a try :)